# jquery each loop into a multi array, check for duplicates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, session

I think what I want to do is really simple but can't get it to work.  I'm looping through a table and getting some values from the existing rows, that part works.  Then I'm using AJAX to  try and make a multidimensional array without duplicates but something isn't working.  What I really want to do is delete the duplicate part, reorder the array and array_push new values.  Here's what I have:

AJAX:

```
function getData(){
    $("#table .mainTR").each(function(){
        var key = $(this).find(".key").text();
        var sel = $(this).find(".s").val();
        var q = $(this).find(".q").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {key: key, s: sel, q: q}
        });
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])){
$title = $_POST['key'];
$s = $_POST['s'];
$q = $_POST['q'];
if(!empty($_SESSION['check'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['check'] as $key=>$value){
        if(in_array($title, $value)){
            unset ($_SESSION['check'][$title]);
            $_SESSION['check'] = array_values($_SESSION['check']);
            array_push($_SESSION['check'], array("key"=>$title, "s"=>$s, "q"=>$q));
        }
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['check'] = array(array("key"=>$title, "s"=>$s, "q"=>$q));
}
}
```

Is there something wrong with the logic?  It seems like it should work.  The same foreach loop works when trying to delete a table row.  It finds the correct KEY and deletes it.  Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: May you clarify a bit? What part is working? PHP? In the meanwhile, I notice that you're firing $.ajax for each and every "#table .mainTR". Maybe preparing a data structure and send it via $.ajax only once could be a first step.

Comment: The part that works is getting the correct row data in jQuery.  And yeah, I noticed that it's being fired as many times as there are rows.  How would you suggest I prepare?  Combine the data together and then separate in PHP?

Comment: Serialize the request as JSON, deserialize it via `json_decode` in PHP. Plus do not use `async: false`.

Comment: Thanks for that advice.  Looking into it now.  But what about the PHP part?  Where did I go wrong there?

Comment: In what way is it not working? What's supposed to be put in the session variable, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: The values of $title, $s, and $q are supposed to be put into the session variable.  The get put in but when something changes with the $s or $q, they get added onto the session array.  If something is changed to either variable, I want to delete that $title array and insert the new one with the changes.  Not sure if I'm making myself clear...hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I got by hours and hours of searching.  I avoided using serialize since...well I don't understand how to use it.  In JS I'm looping to find values in the table and making an array like this:

```
function getData(){
    var checkArray = new Array();
    $("#shopCart .mainTR").each(function(){
        var key = $(this).find(".key").text();
        var sel = $(this).find(".s").val();
        var q = $(this).find(".q").val();
        checkArray.push(key);
        checkArray.push(sel);
        checkArray.push(q);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {ch: checkArray}
    });
}
```

In my PHP is where I found a cool trick.  Since I'm controlling the data in the array, I know how many values will be in it.  The trick I found is "array_chunk" so for the 3 values I'm doing this:

```
if(isset($_POST['ch']) && (!empty($_POST['ch']))){
    unset($_SESSION['check']);
    $_SESSION['check'] = array_chunk($_POST['ch'], 3);
}
```

So I'm just clearing the session variable and adding the new values.  That eliminates all the checking and clearing and all that.  I'm sure there are better ways to do this but this method is short and works and that's what I'm looking for.  Hope this helps someone!